# spring webflux: how to send Mono<T> in response body with body inserters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

This documentation says: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html

> ServerResponse provides access to the HTTP response. Since it is immutable, you create a ServerResponse with a builder. The builder allows you to set the response status, add response headers, and provide a body. For instance, this is how to create a response with a 200 OK status, a JSON content-type, and a body:

```
Mono<Person> person = ...
ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(person);
```

Similarly I tired to pass `Mono<T>` to the body method of ServerReponse Builder but I get following error :

[image]

Code snippet :

**Compilation error**:

```
Mono<Inventory> inventoryMono=request.bodyToMono(Inventory.class);        
 return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(inventoryMono);
```

However it works with below code:

```
ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(inventoryMono.doOnNext(inventoryRepository::save).log(),Inventory.class)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Did you try,  ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(inventoryMono, inventory.class);

Answer (score 1):

Your situation can be explained based on the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerResponse.BodyBuilder.html#body-P-java.lang.Class-). Since you're trying to return a `Mono` (which inherits from the `Publisher` class), you must specify the class as the second parameter in the body method as follows.

`.body(inventoryMono, Inventory.class)`

In your second code snippet, you have the `Inventory.class` as a second parameter, that's why it works. Simply add it to your first code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it's a problem with docs because [ServerResponse.BodyBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/server/ServerResponse.BodyBuilder.html) doesn't contain such method. There is only one one-argument method called *body* which takes [BodyInserter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyInserter.html), so you have to transform Mono to BodyInserter (using [BodyInserters.fromObject](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/5.0.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyInserters.html#fromObject-T-) for example).

Comment: ya, but I would pass one of the reactive stream type rather than using BodyInserters.fromObject. Lets hope for framework support to do the transformation